# Set theory, difference between mapping and extension KREYSZIC

Tags: functions

I understand mapping.
Someone, please help me understand this description of extension.
[Set Extension description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA6WQ.png)

Comment: What is your problem with the given definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a function $g$ with domain $D_{1}$ and a function $f$ with domain $D_{2}$ and $D_{2}\subset D_{1}$ then we say that $g$ is an *extension* of $f$ if $g(x)=f(x)~\forall x\in D_{2}$. Similarly, if $D_{2}\subsetneq D_{1}$ then we say that $g$ is a *proper* extension of $f$.

Comment: It is quite clear now. In which textbook do you get this definition? Thanks.

Comment: I don’t really know a specific book where this definition is given, but I think that is a pretty standard definition